# Does perfino 4.0 supports mysql?

Tags: perfino

Tried new version of perfino (4.0), but didn't find a way to connect it to MySQL.
Is support of MySQL dropped in new version?

Comment: Why not ask their support?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Official MySql support has indeed been dropped in 4.0, only the built-in database is supported from this point on.